# Bad encoding using URL().readText() with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, character-encoding

I try to get the response of my call in a String but the result look like if the charset defined is not good.

```
val apiResponse = URL("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow")
        .readText(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"))
println(apiResponse)
```

I try using "UTF-8" but the result is the same, full of badly encoded characters.
Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The server returns the web page compressed with gzip**, so it naturally includes lots of undisplayable characters.

You can confirm this without using Kotlin, e.g.:

```
$ wget 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow'

[output snipped]

$ file 'questions\?order=desc\&sort=activity\&site=stackoverflow'
questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow: gzip compressed data, from TOPS/20, original size 19820
```

You can use Kotlin to uncompress it — but this is easier if you read the URL as bytes, to avoid any character-set conversions:

```
val url = URL("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow")
val content = GZIPInputStream(ByteArrayInputStream(url.readBytes()))
    .bufferedReader()
    .use { it.readText() }
```